# Issues testing data in an Angular route definition

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to test a component that dynamically sets a title based on data in a route, but I'm having trouble with the testing bit.

I'm trying to mock out the route data, but in my method for grabbing the data `findRouteData` it just ends up undefined when debugging the tests.

I can visually verify that the component itself does what I want it to do, but I'm having trouble with mocking the route data bit.

Like I said, everything is being called, but my mock of the routerState isn't working properly. Data is undefined.

How do I properly mock the route data?

```
@Injectable()
class FakeRouter {
    url: string;
    subject = new Subject();
    events = this.subject.asObservable();
    routerState = {
        snapshot: {
            root: {
                data: {title: 'Title'}
            }
        }
    };
    navigate(url: Array<string>): void {
        this.url = url.join('');
        this.triggerNavEvents(this.url);
    }

    triggerNavEvents(url: string): void {
        this.subject.next(new NavigationEnd(0, url, null));
    }
}
```

The component itself:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
    selector: 'hq-page-title',
    templateUrl: './page-title.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page-title.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PageTitleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public title;
    private unsubscribe = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(private router: Router, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.router.events
            .filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
            .subscribe(() => {
                const test = this.router;
                const test1 = this.router.routerState;
                const routeData = this.findRouteData(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root);
                if (routeData.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
                    this.title = routeData.title;
                    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
                }
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe.next();
        this.unsubscribe.complete();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the route data
     *
     * Check out the following links to see why it was implemented this way:
     * @link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19420
     * @link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11812#issuecomment-346637722
     *
     * @param {ActivatedRouteSnapshot} root
     * @returns {any}
     */
    private findRouteData(root: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        let data = <any>{};
        while (root) {
            if (root.children && root.children.length) {
                root = root.children[0];
            } else if (root.data) {
                data = {...data, ...root.data};
                return data;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

An example route:

```
{
    path: 'settings',
    data: {title: 'Settings'},
}
```

The tests:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PageTitleComponent } from './page-title.component';
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class FakeRouter {
    url: string;
    subject = new Subject();
    events = this.subject.asObservable();
    routerState = {
        snapshot: {
            root: {
                data: {title: 'Title'}
            }
        }
    };
    navigate(url: Array<string>): void {
        this.url = url.join('');
        this.triggerNavEvents(this.url);
    }

    triggerNavEvents(url: string): void {
        this.subject.next(new NavigationEnd(0, url, null));
    }
}

describe('PageTitleComponent', () => {
    let component: PageTitleComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageTitleComponent>;
    let router: Router;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [
                PageTitleComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: router, useClass: FakeRouter }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageTitleComponent);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;

                router = TestBed.get(Router);
                fixture.detectChanges();
            });
    }));
    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('the title should be title', () => {
        beforeEach(async(() => {
            router.navigate(['']);
        }));
        it('the title should be title', () => {
            expect(component.title).toBe('Title');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem, as these things often go.

Rather than trying to go into the `router.routerState` to get the route data, I switched to using the `ActivatedRoute`, and used the snapshot from that. I had shied away from that implementation earlier because I found that subscribing to the `ActivatedRoute`'s `data` property didn't yield the route `data`. It just ended up being a blank object.

However, I found that if I looked into the `ActivatedRoute` once the route events had reached `NavigationEnd` all the data I was looking for was there.

`ActivatedRoute` was much easier to mock. Inside `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` I added this piece to the providers:

```
{
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useValue: {
        snapshot: {
            data: {title: 'Title'}
        }
    },
},
```

The changes in my main TS file are these:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
        .filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
        .subscribe(() => {
            const routeData = this.findRouteData(this.activatedRoute.snapshot);
            if (routeData.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
                this.title = routeData.title;
                this.cdRef.detectChanges();
            }
        });
}
```

And I removed this bit from the mock router:

```
routerState = {
    snapshot: {
        root: {
            data: {title: 'Title'}
        }
    }
};
```

Really not too many changes.

**Note:** I could still be missing something here. Please let me know if you think I am.